# Registering domain with NIC handle?

Tags: domain-name-system, whois, domain-registration

Many moons ago I was a system administrator for a small company. I vaguely remember that when I registered domains, they would be using a "handle" which I think was for me "BP897". My previous employer is now having issues with some of the domains being stolen because "admin" contact which was associated with his domains was using an email address that I haven't used in probably 20 years.

Since he was the technical contact for the domains, he was able to renew the registrations over the years without any issues, so he never noticed that my old email was the admin address. I'm working with him and Network Solutions to try to lock down the remaining domains, and to see if there is any chance of recovering the stolen one.

In any case, I've been trying to find information on what I thought was my NIC handle, "BP897", but I'm not sure where to look. I also might be wrong about the handle "id", so I wanted to know if there was a way to search handles using first/last names.

Comment: In which NIC? BP897 doesn't seem to be a valid NIC handle anywhere that I looked.

Comment: I thought that it was with Network Solutions, but it appears that they might have changed formats. I forget who else it could have been with.

Comment: It could have been EasyDNS as well. How do you do a NIC lookup for  a particular registrar?

Comment: If you provided some domain names related to your problem, It would have helped people to help you.